# How to use `scp` command copy a folder while not rewrite the local file with same name?

Tags: linux, unix, scp

I am using `scp` to copy a folder from remote server, however, the it broke during the copy procedure,  I am trying to re-scp, but I just don't want to over-write files in the folder that have been copied to the local.

So is it possible to use `scp` to copy a folder from remote server while don't over-write the destination local file with same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `rsync`. The syntax is almost the same, it works over ssh too, and it intelligently transfers only differences between files. Example:

```
rsync *.jpg hostname:yourdir
```